# tooltips on another site

Tags: jquery, css

I just stumbled on a site that has nice tooltips: https://www.wetransfer.com/

You can see the tooltips whenever you hover on an "i" button or "en" button.

Any tips on how to repeat this fade in/fade out effect?

Comment: You could use Flash, like they do

Comment: @devdigital: Flash is not available on any platform (especially on mobile devices) and is known for performance / security issues. Thus, many visitors won't have it installed or deactivated.

Comment: The only tip that I can give you is to try implement it yourself and  if you come across any problems, come post a more specific question here.  As your question stands right now it is not a good fit for our Q&A format.  We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: @winSharp93. I was being sarcastic.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without jQuery with CSS3 - http://jsfiddle.net/cTUgH/3/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">
    i <span> Tooltip Content </span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    display: block;
    margin: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    background: #eee;
    color: #888;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font: italic bold 16px/30px Georgia;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

span {
    display: block;
    height: 230px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    background: #eee;
    color: #888;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: 55px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

a:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Zoltan, but css3 is not cross platform yet, isnt it? As I know IE do not support it yet.

Answer (score 2):

[This is how it's done with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Az4CW/)

Of course, you could replace the effect with an array of different types, such as swing, bounce, ease-in-ease-out, etc. That's up to you, but there's the jist of the jQuery version.

**The Markup**

```
<div id="mydiv" rel="This is where we hold the tooltip info for ease of use."> Hover this div. </div>
```

**The CSS**

```
#mydiv{
  position:relative;
  width:100px;   
}
#tips{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:105px;
  background:#ccc;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:5px; 
  opacity:0;
}
```

**The jQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $('#mydiv').hover(function(){
    $(this).append('<div id="tips">'+$(this).attr('rel')+'</div>');
    $('#tips').fadeTo(300, 1);
  }, function(){
    $('#tips').fadeTo(300, 0);
    $('#tips', this).remove();
  });
});
```

**Edit**

Leaving original answer intact, a more specific request was made and I'm going to oblige.

*I don't use the 'ease-out' method for the animation, instead, I simply animate the left distance and the opacity.*

[I believe this is more keen to what you desire](http://jsfiddle.net/Az4CW/2/)

Comment: It doesnt look alike, but it is something similar. I liked css3 sample more but it is not cros platform. Ohgodwhy, can you edit you sample with ease out effect?

Comment: @user1016695 Added new fiddle at the end of the answer addressing your request. And yes, the CSS3 solution is more elegant, but as you said, the support is not quite there yet.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIS they use flash, but the same effects could be reproduced easily with jQuery for example. It has fade-in, fade-out effects out of the box.